# Injecting a JavaScript into a webpage automatically?

Tags: javascript

I am a very novice when it comes to writing code, this is my first attempt. I have done a fair amount of research and learning, but there is so much to learn. So i'm looking for some help or advice. At work we have to click a button to get us a work order. I am trying to automate the process, I have some code written that clicks the button for me. Unfortunately when it returns with "No Matches" it automatically reloads the page and my code is gone in the DOM. Is there a way to automatically inject my code every time the webpage reloads?

My Current Code:

```
var button = document.getElementById('GetMeAWorkOrder')

     setInterval

     button.click()

 ,1500
```

Comment: You can create a bookmarklet, which is a bookmark in your browser that runs code.  This website will allow you to paste in your code, create the bookmarklet and shows you how to add it to your browser: https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/

Comment: There's probably a browser extension for this. Depends on which browser you are using.

Comment: I am using Chrome and have Tamper Monkey, but am struggling to find out how to use it.

Comment: You can use TamperMonkey to update your userscripts.
https://www.tampermonkey.net/

Comment: You can open "editor" tab on clicking the "Dashboard" menu in Tampermonkey plugin. There you can enter your custom script

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is this a work device? I.e. are you able to install custom extensions that you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into creating [your own Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) that injects the code through a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). To make it easier, I've included the starter files for your specific project. Simply entering your specific URL into the marked lines should be enough for the code you posted.

**Manifest.json**

```
{
     "manifest_version": 2,
     "name": "My Extension",
     "description": "Injects custom code to [website]",
     "version": "1",
     "permissions": [
          "*://URL HERE*"
     ],
     "content_scripts": [
          {
               "matches": [
                    "*://URL HERE*"
               ],
               "js": ["content.js"]
          }
      ]
}
```

**content.js**

```
//code you want to inject into the website
var button = document.getElementById('GetMeAWorkOrder');

setInterval( function() { button.click() },1500 );
```

Remember to replace the URLS with the website you want to inject the code into; here's a reference on [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/match_patterns).

Good luck and have fun coding! :)

Comment: This seems like it will be the best option for me. I'm unable to install programs to my computer at work, but I am able to add extensions. So I will have to write the extension at home and then transfer it to my work computer. I will give it my best shot this weekend, and hopefully Monday morning it will work. Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: @AustinBendik No problem! Remember that these two text files need to be stored locally. If that's not possible, you can pay $5 to verify a Chrome extension developer account and host it on the Chrome Web Store (They have options to create a private listing).